# c++ get values of an unordered_map of vector of unordered_map

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

I have a C++ program that has one `unordered_map` (unmap_graph) with a `vector` in its value (vector_id_as2), and this `vector` is another `unordered_map` (unmap_id_as2) with a `vector` of int in its value. Look at C++ code below:

```
typedef unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> unmap_id_as2; 
typedef vector<unmap_id_as2> vector_id_as2;
typedef unordered_map<int, vector_id_as2> unmap_graph;

unmap_id_as2 map2_1;
map2_1[67031]={1,432414};
unmap_id_as2 map2_2;
map2_2[67030]={2,432413};
unmap_id_as2 map2_3;
map2_3[67053]={2,432444};
unmap_id_as2 map2_4;
map2_4[67053]={3,432445};

vector_id_as2 vetor_id_as2 = {map2_1, map2_2, map2_3, map2_4};

unmap_graph map1;
map1[67029] = vetor_id_as2;

cout << "***********: 432414 - " << map1[67029][0][67031][1] << endl;
cout << "***********: 2 - " << map1[67029][1][67030][0] << endl;
cout << "***********: 432413 - " << map1[67029][1][67030][1] << endl;
cout << "***********: 3 - " << map1[67029][3][67053][0] << endl;
```

My question is: How can I loop in **map1** to get inside map (`unmap_id_as2`) keys and values? For example, at `cout << "***********: 432414 - " << map1[67029][0][67031][1] << endl;` command, a got the result **432414**. But I informed all map1 parametes ([67029][0][67031][1]) to do it. So I want to know how can I loop in map1 to get all its values (that is a vector of another unordered_map)?

Emerson

Comment: _How can I loop in map1_ ... did you try writing a loop? Was there a problem with it? Do you know how to write loops?

Comment: Useless, I edited my first question to clarify my question. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
typedef unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> unmap_id_as2; 
typedef vector<unmap_id_as2> vector_id_as2;
typedef unordered_map<int, vector_id_as2> unmap_graph;
```

So looping over an `unmap_graph` happens in the reverse order:

```
for (auto& [my_int, my_vector_id_as2] : map1)
    for (auto& my_unmap_id_as2 : my_vector_id_as2)
        for (auto& [my_inner_int, my_vector_ints] : my_unmap_id_as2)
        {
            std::cout << my_inner_int << ":";
            for (int my_innermost_int : my_vector_ints)
                std::cout << " " << my_innermost_int;
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
```

(Consider using `const auto&`s if you don't need to mutate/change data).

Comment: since youve pointed it out, it's not 100% of the cases where using `auto&` is faster that `auto`

Comment: @AryanParekh That's right.  A good rule of thumb is don't deep-copy when when some of the items are larger than `int` / "word" size on the architecture.  That's why I did copy to `my_innermost_int`, but none of the others.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Ranged-based-loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) in C++ to iterate through the map

```cpp
std::unordered_map<int,std::string> names{
{1,"John"},
{3,"Geoff"},
{2,"Parekh"},
};


//Iterating through the map
for (auto [key,value] : names)
{
    std::cout << key <<  " : " << value << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2 : Parekh
3 : Geoff
1 : John
```

If you want to loop through nested maps, where the value of one is another map, you need to nest the loops too.

```cpp
for (auto [key,value] : names)
{
    //value is now the vector of un_ordered map
    for( auto map : value){
         for (auto [key2,value2] : map)
         {
           /// .....

         }
    }
}
```

This is the only way you can go through every map in the container, I do suggest that you rethink your container choice as this will be **highly** in-efficient.

Comment: Aryan Parenkh, thank you for the feedback, but I know how to loop in a simple string map. My question is how do I loop in a unordered_map of vector of another unordered_map values.

Comment: @AryanParekh: `auto map : value` does a deep copy (allocating extra memory, copying all elements, later destructing/deleting all elements) of each element in the `value` container - not a good idea with these deeply nested containers.
*"rethink your container choice as this will be highly in-efficient"* - it's only meaningful to talk about the code being inefficient in the context of some lesser amount of work actually wanted done.  If all nodes must be visited, it's not necessarily inefficient, especially if `unmap_id_as2`'s vectors hold largish numbers of elements.

Comment: he's keeping a map of vector of maps , is that efficient?

Comment: @TonyDelroy does doing `auto& ` help?

Comment: @AryanParekh: *"is [map of vector of maps] efficient?" - maps are efficient to lookup/maintain by key, vectors are efficient to iterate due to contiguous memory: if his operations suit those data structures, it's efficient.  We can't say if they do or not without understanding his data.  And yes - `auto&` or `const auto&` help - depending on whether the content will be mutated/changed.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I think you are right again. My map1 is like a graph, where the keys are vertices and the map1 values vector is the edges list with another vertices. The problem is that I need to keep some information of each edges, so I used another map to keep then. When I receive a vertex, I look for it in map1 by the key, and got all its neighbors in the vector of map. So, I use the internal parameters (the value field of internal map) to make a decision.